# Migrate from older Dell XPS to new One?

Tags: laptop, backup, data-recovery, disk-image, dell-xps

My old work place let me keep my current Dell XPS 15 9510 (win 11), this laptop is perfectly set-up for all of my work and software dev needs. My new work place have issued me with a new Dell XPS 15 9530 (win 11). Which is soon going to be shipped out to me.

I really don't want to spend a day re-setting up new work laptop again.

Is there any MS way I can use to help re-image my new work laptop?

Is this even a good idea, any reasons why i should no do it ?

Comment: A request to recommend 3rd party software will get closed in seconds… if you reword it to 'any built-in Microsoft' way [which will perhaps be something like sysprep but i'm not all that good on MS stuff] then it has a chance to stay open & perhaps get an answer.

Comment: Why waste your time? Email your manager something like: "yo i have that same laptop should i waste 2 days setting everything up or can i swap mine for yours?" and boom.

Comment: Is this even a good idea, any reasons why i should no do it ?   .....   Most of the time yes.  You wind up bringing old errors over and spend more time fixing the errors.

Comment: Yes, there are MS ways for your laptop to be configured with your profile and settings, but your org needs to support these. You'll need to ask them.

Comment: @music2myear We have zero group policies on my remote machine -- they just ship me a new one -- and i am trust to get on with the job. They have zero 'IT' like set-up and config that is needed for dev laptops. Hence why i want to mirror my current XPS.

Answer (score 1):

The two laptop models are very close, so a clone of the operating system
of one should work on the other, on condition that the new disk is at least
as large as the old one.

You should ensure that the new laptop boots fine and that Windows
is activated. Windows from the old laptop will then be activated
automatically on the new one by its digital license.

You should have one or two USB disks for the following :

- Take a backup disk image of the old laptop
- Take a backup disk image of the new laptop (to be able to undo)
- Boot the new laptop using boot media and restore to it the Windows
  from the old one.

My favorite product is
[AOMEI Backupper Freeware](https://www.ubackup.com/free-backup-software.html)
with its
[AOMEI Bootable Media](https://www.ubackup.com/help/create-bootable-disk.html),
but there exist alternate products.
AOMEI only backs up used sectors, so the backup image is smaller than
the disk.

Comment: *Caveat:* The new laptop might contain newer apps from IT, such as a different anti-malware suite, or newly licensed versions of an office suite. It might be best to check with IT if there are changes that would be lost.

Comment: I agree, especially apps installed specially for/by the new work place.

Comment: Honestly, this is the first remote dev job that I have taken where there are IT pre-installed/forced apps/spyware on the machine .. its virtually a brand new machine as thought I went to dell.com and had it delivered to my house and then i expensed back to the business.

Comment: In that case there's no problem. Some company computers arrive with VPN etc installed, but this seems like it's not so in your case.